# Не запускается Ultralight Java

Tags: java, ultralight

Я использую ultralight-java https://github.com/LabyMod/ultralight-java ~ https://ultralig.ht/

Так вот, я инициализирую его в init()

```
public static void init() {
        try {
            ResourceManager.loadUltralight();
        } catch (URISyntaxException | UltralightLoadException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        UltralightPlatform platform = UltralightPlatform.instance();
        platform.setConfig(
                new UltralightConfig()
                        .fontHinting(FontHinting.SMOOTH)
                        .resourcePath(ResourceManager.ultraLightDir.getAbsolutePath())
        );
        platform.usePlatformFontLoader();
        platform.usePlatformFileSystem(ResourceManager.ultraLightDir.getAbsolutePath());
        renderer = UltralightRenderer.create();
    }
```

ResourceManager.loadUltralight()

```
String rootPath = "/assets/anthrocore";

        copyFolderFromJar(rootPath + "/public", new File(ultraLightDir, "public").toPath());
        copyFolderFromJar(rootPath + "/bin", binDir.toPath());
        copyFolderFromJar(rootPath + "/resources", resourceDir.toPath());

        UltralightJava.extractNativeLibrary(binDir.toPath());
        UltralightGPUDriverNativeUtil.extractNativeLibrary(binDir.toPath());

        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "UltralightCore.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "glib-2.0-0.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "gobject-2.0-0.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "gmodule-2.0-0.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "gio-2.0-0.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "gstreamer-full-1.0.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "WebCore.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "Ultralight.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "ultralight-java-gpu.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "AppCore.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
        System.load(new File(binDir.toPath().toFile(), "ultralight-java.dll").toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

Но после всего этого, как я выяснил во время выполнения нативного метода UltralightRenderer.create();
У меня просто вылетает, без какой либо ошибки
https://imgur.com/a/PhTvOrH